# DRYing up Inherited Methods in Rails Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, inheritance, model-view-controller

I have a base set of controllers with a pretty standard set of RESTful methods. I then have a second set of controllers for managing client micro-sites. The second set of controllers are almost identical to the base set, except that each method that responds with HTML needs an additional instance variable representing the micro-site's id (which is not available to the base controllers) to be defined.

This means I'm repeating my code twice in my app and that's not very maintainable, especially for a large app with many controllers. Is there a way to tell a controller to inherit a method, but to then insert an additional variable or other logic into the inherited method?

For example, if I have a UsersController below:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
end
```

And then I have Clients::UsersController << UsersController below:

```
class Clients::UsersController < UsersController
    def index
        @client_id = params[:id]
    end
end
```

How can I DRY up Clients::UsersController?

Comment: Very hard to tell you anything useful since you've omitted all the relevant code. At this point, we could suggest "put `lots of flow control` in a method" and not much else.

Comment: The code is not terribly relevant. This isn't a question on a specific piece of code. It's a question on design patterns. I could post all the code for my controller, but 99% of it is irrelevant to the question, which is why I opted for a generic example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably after a [concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html):

```
# app/controllers/concerns/do_something.rb

module DoSomething
  include ActiveSupport::Concern

  def something
    # Shared code goes here
  end
end
```

In your controllers...

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    include DoSomething

    def index
      # Invoke shared code
      something
    end
end

class Clients::UsersController < UsersController
    include DoSomething

    def index
      @client_id = params[:id]

      # Invoke shared code
      something
    end
end
```